# Windows does not recognize USB devices any more

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a Windows 7 installation. When I connect new USB devices these devices are not recognized as hot plug devices. I have to restart windows to get these devices working.

Some time ago I turned off some services (I can't remember which ones) that I was thought that I do not need them. Perhaps one was too much, but I don't know which.

Comment: Edit your question and specify which services you disabled.  Without this information it will be difficult to answer your question.  If this cannot be done disregard this comment.  If you cannot or are unwilling to provide this information please don’t reply to this comment

Comment: Yes @ramhound is right (again). Without knowing what you did it is nearly impossible for us to help

Comment: you are missing the point. the two are most likely unrelated. there is no USB service in windows 7

Comment: This is my problem: I do not remember which services I turned off. Otherwise I could easily turn them on again and check.

Answer (score 1):

Teddy,

There is no service in windows 7 for USB.
The devices are handled by the USB hub on the motherboard. You can update the drivers via your Mobo models support site.

Additionally, if you think something's wrong with the drivers you are running. Go to device manager and completely uninstall the USB hub. Restart the computer, windows will find it at startup and reinstall it.

I would recommend updating the drivers for it.

"There's no such service. You can enable or disable the port." - arnavsharma (MCC, Partner, MVP) Moderator of Microsoft technet forums

These methods may also help you figure out your issue. You can search for these steps individually on Google, or the link to support.microsoft.com has detailed step by step for each item.

1: Run the automated troubleshooter for your version of Windows.

2: Make sure that the drive has a drive letter assigned in Disk Management.

3: Make sure that the disk drive is Enabled

4: Your USB drive may be corrupted

References:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a6d44cfe-4973-4d51-a18f-8bc30aa40240/usb-service-name-in-windows-7?forum=w7itproui

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/330140/my-drive-does-not-appear-in-windows-explorer-view
Hope this helps

Comment: Who has downvoted this question? Actually I would have told him to do the same - removing all USB devices helps in many cases.

Comment: @davidbaumann An answer full of links is unhelpful.  There isn’t a single reference quoted or cited.  Answers with links, and where no citations or quotation is made isn’t helpful in my opinion.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I will when I get a chance. I figured Microsoft would be around for a while. 

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - MS is notorious for retiring links without warning, once that happens they stop working all together, even though the reference still exist in some capacity.  An example of this happening is with the C++ Redistributables, one day the old download links stopped working, hence the reason we have dozens of questions on that subject.  When you have properly cited and quoted your reference links I will revert my vote.

Comment: No worries, I get your point.